# Facing issue with spark installation

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

Getting below error while trying to start pyspark.
Installed python, java before spark.

Please provide the necessay suggestion to resolve the issue.

Thanks

```
C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\bin>pyspark
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/06/18 00:24:04 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/06/18 00:24:05 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py:42: UserWarning: Failed to initialize Spark session.
  warnings.warn("Failed to initialize Spark session.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession._create_shell_session()  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 553, in _create_shell_session
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1585, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

C:\Spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\bin>SUCCESS: The process with `PID 16952 (child process of PID 1576)` has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with `PID 1576 (child process of PID 6768)` has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with `PID 6768 (child process of PID 6460)` has been terminated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you able to run spark-shell without pyspark?

Comment: there was an issue with java version. After installing java version 8, the issue got resolved.